# How to annotate a related object to queryset, in cases it exists, and None otherwise? (Django)

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Folks, I have a Django chat app where people form groups and post replies under them. Whenever a user views replies in a group, a "seen object" is created (and stored) for the said reply and the said user.

This way, I'm able to show a **new tag** in front of all unseen replies for every user in each group.

**My question is:** To each object in a queryset of replies, how can I append a seen object corresponding to each reply, for a particular user? Where no such object exists, it will remain None I presume.

The related models are:

```
class Reply(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(validators=[MaxLengthValidator(500)])
    writer = models.ForeignKey(User)
    submitted_on = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, auto_now_add=True)

class Seen(models.Model):
    seen_user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    seen_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    which_reply = models.ForeignKey(Reply)
```

Seen objects are created for replies a user has seen; they're not created otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a `Prefetch` object:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related

e.g.

```
seen_qs = Seen.objects.filter(user=request.user)
replies_qs = Reply.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('seen_set', queryset=seen_qs)
)
```

On Django < 1.7 you'll can do two queries and combine them in the view, e.g.

```
seen_for = {
    seen.which_reply_id: seen
    for seen in Seen.objects.filter(user=request.user)
}
replies_qs = Reply.objects.filter(whatever)

# you could attach the Seen instance to each Reply
# or just make a paired list e.g.
replies = [
    (reply, seen_for.get(reply.pk))  # None if not found
    for reply in replies_qs
]
```

Comment: if the related object had a unique existence, could I also use `select_related`?

Comment: yes, `select_related` is good for ForeignKey and OneToOne... here you have a reverse-ForeignKey so you need prefetch with a queryset (same for ManyToMany)

Comment: One problem: I'm on Django 1.5, meaning I can't use `queryset=seen_qs`

Comment: ok in older Django you're going to need two querysets and combine them in your code, see updated answer

Comment: Fair enough! Once this is passed as a queryset to my template, I'll iterate through object_list and access a reply as `object[0]`, and its related seen object (if it exists) via `object[1]` right?

Comment: Hmm, when I'm testing it, seems `object.0` and `object.1` is the way to go in templates.

Comment: alternatively use "destructuring assignment" (tuple unpacking) e.g. `{% for reply, seen in replies %}`